# Using AJAX To complete autopredict - Not working

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Having a problem with an AJAX JS feature which will grab information from the PHP database and predict the search term before the user has finished.

***/js/primary.js:***

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $('.autosuggest').keyup(function() {

                    var search_term = $(this).attr('value');
                    //alert(search_term); //takes what is typed in the input and alerts it
                    $.post('ajax/search.php', {search_term:search_term}, function (data) {
                        alert('Ajax Activated');
                        $('.result').html(data);
                                    $('.result li').click(function() {
                                            var result_value = $(this).text();
                                            var id_result = $(this).data("id");
                                            $('.autosuggest').attr('value', result_value);
                                            $('.id').attr('value', id_result);
                                            $('.result').html(''); 
                                    });
                    });
                });
            });
```

***/ajax/search.php:***

```
            require_once '../Configuration.php';
            if (isset($_POST['search_term']) == true && empty ($_POST['search_term']) == false) {

            $search_term = mysqli_real_escape_string($sql_connection, $_POST['search_term']);


            $query = mysqli_query($sql_connection,"SELECT `id`,`customer_name`,`postcode` FROM `Customers` WHERE `customer_name` LIKE '$search_term%' ");

            while(($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) !== false) {
                //loop
                  echo '<li data-id="',$row['id'],'" >',$row['customer_name'],' ',$row['postcode'],'</li>';

                }
            }


            ?>
```

***Selectcustomer.php:***

```
                        $customer_id = (int) $_GET['id'];

                        $query = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE id = {$customer_id}";

                        $result = mysqli_query($sql_connection, $query) or die('<p>' . $query . '</p><div>' . 
                                               mysqli_error($sql_connection) . '</div>');

                        $customer = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);  

            ?>
             <h2>Quick find users</h2>
                            <div class="block ">

                            <form action="Customer.php" method="post">


                            <input type="text" class="autosuggest"> <input type="submit" value="Go Go Go!">
                                <div class="dropdown">
                                    <ul class="result">
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <input type="hidden" name="id" class="id" value="">
                            </form> 




                            </div>
```

Problem:
Nothing is appearing in the field (This used to work).

I fixed all of the paths not working. But it still doesn't prompt a search.

Comment: Are you getting `data` in the ajax method?

Comment: From what I can see, I'm not getting anything

Comment: Check your console for errors in GOogle chrome by clicking f12 and going to console.  Refresh your page and if there aren't any errors, go to your Network panel, refresh the page and see if your ajax request succeeds or fails.

Comment: Hey User, I can't see where to relocate those files, if I put them on my root it's fine. I think the external script is calling them. Which is annoying because I need it to be elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was directed to look in Search.php which contained an infinite loop:

```
        while(($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) !== false) {
            //loop
              echo '<li data-id="',$row['id'],'" >',$row['customer_name'],' ',$row['postcode'],'</li>';
```

Changed it to:

```
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            //loop
              echo '<li data-id="',$row['id'],'" >',$row['customer_name'],' ',$row['postcode'],'</li>';
```